# Azure billing invoice url not available

Tags: azure, powershell

I try to download my Azure invoices, but I cannot access the urls generated by the `Get-AzureRmBillingInvoice` command.

`Get-AzureRmBillingInvoice -Latest` returns only Name, InvoicePeriodStartDate, InvoicePeriodEndDate, no URL.

`Get-AzureRmBillingInvoice -GenerateDownloadUrl` tough, returns all the invoices, with the DownloadUrl property filled. Fine, I can live with that.

```
$invoice = Get-AzureRmBillingInvoice -GenerateDownloadUrl
$invoice
```

this also returns the all the invoices with the url's.
Here comes the strange part:

`$invoice[0] | fl` does not list neither the `DownloadUrl`, nor the `DownloadUrlExpiry` property.

`Get-AzureRmBillingInvoice -GenerateDownloadUrl | ForEach-Object { Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ($_.DownloadUrl) -OutFile ($downloadDirectory + '\' + $_.Name + '.pdf')}`

This gives an error: `Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Uri'. The argument is null or empty.`

I didn't finy any way to actually make use of the generated url. What am I doing wrong?

edit:
The url of the last invoice is not generated.
`$invoice[0] | fl` returns:

```
Name                   : XXXXXXXXXX
InvoicePeriodStartDate : 2021-05-22
InvoicePeriodEndDate   : 2021-06-21
```

while
`$invoice[1] | fl` returns:

```
Name                   : XXXXXXXXXX
InvoicePeriodStartDate : 2021-04-22
InvoicePeriodEndDate   : 2021-05-21
DownloadUrl            : https://commercecachepublic.blob.core.windows.net/invoices/...
DownloadUrlExpiry      : 7/5/2021 5:14:24 PM
```

The type of the both is `Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Billing.Models.PSInvoice`.

Comment: I cannot test this, but  _"Because Az PowerShell modules now have all the capabilities of AzureRM PowerShell modules and more, we'll retire AzureRM PowerShell modules on 29 February 2024."_, you could try with [Get-AzBillingInvoice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.billing/get-azbillinginvoice?view=azps-6.1.0) instead

Comment: Thank you. This was better, but still doesn't give the last invoice url.

Comment: Could you post whatever `$invoice[0] | fl *` returns? I'm also curious about `$invoice[0].GetType().FullName`

Comment: @Theo I updated the post with the answers.

Comment: It seems then not all invoices have a download url.. Perhaps something wrong with these? You could do `Get-AzBillingInvoice -GenerateDownloadUrl | Where-Object { ![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.DownloadUrl) } | ForEach-Object {...}` ?